How can I unbind a device without sudo?
Currently I use the following command to disable / enable my touchscreen.
sudo bash -c 'echo "<device-id>" > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind'
Is there a way to achieve this without requiring me to enter my password every time? I'd specifically like to bind it to a shortcut.

It has root owner and 0400 permission, so only root or a process with CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE capabilities can write to it.
You could create a simple bash script
#!/bin/bash
echo "<device-id>" > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind

and arrange for sudo to permit you to execute just this script with privilege and without password. How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?
Alternatively you could write a trivial program, compile it to a binary, and then give the binary privileges to do this.  Preferably:
$ sudo setcap CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE ./myprog

see man pages for capabilities(7) and setcap(8).

I created a bash script and added the necessary permission to /etc/sudoers. I can now run the command without a password, so thank you already for that.
Unfortunately it had the side effect of making all other calls using sudo (e.g. sudo nano test) take several seconds until the password is requested. Is that normal?
